# Remove [Website name] from email subject line in WordPress emails

Tags: php, wordpress

WordPress (self-hosted account) emails seem to include the website's name in square brackets in the subject line. e.g.

```
[Website Name] this is a not-so great email subject line
```

How can the website name that appears in square brackets be removed? Is there a filter available?

Comment: Are you talking about the emails sent as part of an RSS (subscription) feed? Is it a self-hosted account or a wordpress.com account?

Comment: Hi jboneca - it's a self hosted account i.e. WordPress.org. I'm talking about all system emails sent out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has been forever since I worked with Wordpress, but the function you need to look for is `wp_mail()` where the second argument is the subject.

Search all of your files for that function and edit as appropriate. Without knowing where and why the emails are being sent, I'm not sure anyone here can pinpoint where you should look.

Alternatively, search for all `get_option('blogname')` and `$blogname` to see where the blogname is being prepended to the subject.

Reference:

```
<?php wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments ); ?>
```

[Link to relevant doc](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.8/src/wp-includes/pluggable.php#L0)

Comment: I'm not sure it's as simple as that. I've already filtered several email's $subject but [Website name] continues to be added to the start of the subject. Every single time.

Comment: @henrywright As mentioned, without knowing which emails you're referring to, I can't provide any more information. I've never seen this in my self-hosted Wordpress blogs, unless I specifically designated it to have that subject. Wordpress.com blogs will include the site name in the header of their new post emails as part of the subscription service. When is the email sent, why, and how? Are you using plugins? Have you consulted a psychic?

Comment: Have you consulted a psychic? hehe - thanks jboneca for your help. I'm on the right track now... thanks to you!

Comment: @henrywright no problem sir :) Just keep in mind that Wordpress has other mail functions for specific instances (such as signaling a posted comment, a reply, pingback, etc), so you should look for any variation of "mail" just to be safe.